# Praat: Intensity formulas

Tags: praat

I guess someone on here will have experience using Intensity / Modify / Formula... in Praat. There is some very compressed guidance in the dialogue box itself but I think I must be misunderstanding it. I can't find any examples online either. I'd appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction. For each frame, I want to check whether the intensity is above (louder than) a threshold, and if it is I want to increase it to twice the difference, so for example if my threshold was 5 and the original values for 3 frames were 5 10 7 I would want to end up with 5 15 9.